# bootstrap datepicker validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am trying to use `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js` and I have successfully integrated it in my project. Yet, when I tryg to show today's date as a default value in the `from` input field, it is not working.

Javascript:

```
var d = new Date();

var currDate = d.getDate();
var currMonth = d.getMonth();
var currYear = d.getFullYear();

var dateStr = currDate + "-" + currMonth + "-" + currYear;

$('#from').datetimepicker({
    pickTime: false,
    defaultDate: dateStr
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="From" name="from" id="from" style="width: 90%"/>

<input type="text" placeholder="To" name="to" id="to" style="width: 90%"/>
```

AND with this I would also like to validate the date in `from` filed so that it should not be less than today's date and `to` date not less than tomorrow's date and not greater than 3 month date.

I have searched for an answer on google and Stackoverflow already. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KWvNe/

**HTML**

```
<div class="well">
  <div id="from-datepicker" class="input-append date">
    <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text"></input>
    <span class="add-on">
      <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
      </i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="well">
  <div id="to-datepicker" class="input-append date">
    <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text"></input>
    <span class="add-on">
      <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
      </i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {

    var d = new Date();
    var today = d;
    var dateThreeMonthLater = d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 3);

    $('#from-datepicker').datetimepicker({
      language: 'pt-BR',
      startDate: today,
      endDate: dateThreeMonthLater
    });

     $('#to-datepicker').datetimepicker({
      language: 'pt-BR'
    });

});
```

Check working fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/KWvNe/
do not forgot to include essential javascript and css check here http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

You can set following options for a datepicker

```
  maskInput: true,           // disables the text input mask
  pickDate: true,            // disables the date picker
  pickTime: true,            // disables de time picker
  pick12HourFormat: false,   // enables the 12-hour format time picker
  pickSeconds: true,         // disables seconds in the time picker
  startDate: -Infinity,      // set a minimum date
  endDate: Infinity          // set a maximum date
```

Comment: thanks sir it is working but i want that end date should be 3 months in future according to todays date

Comment: thank you sir it works fine now..but it is not alowing me to slect date from todays upto 3 months.. that is i can only selct todays date and date after 3 months..and i would like to have that user can selcet todays date and date betwwen todays date and 3 month date..

Answer (score 1):

use this jquery function

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
          $("#from").datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd");
          $("#to").datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( "#to").datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
          $("#to").datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd");
          $("#from").datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="From" name="from" id="from" style="width: 90%"/>

<input type="text" placeholder="To" name="to" id="to" style="width: 90%"/>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but after trying your given code it is not even showing me calender to select date

Answer (score 1):

I got ur problem...This is a simple date validation

```
<input type="text" id="txtdate" />
<input value="SUBMIT" id="btnsubmit" onclick="checkDate();"/>
<script>
           function checkDate() {
            var EnteredDate = document.getElementById("txtdate").value; //for javascript
            var EnteredDate = $("#txtdate").val(); // For JQuery
            var date = EnteredDate.substring(0, 2);
            var month = EnteredDate.substring(3, 5);
            var year = EnteredDate.substring(6, 10);
            var myDate = new Date(year, month - 1, date);
            var today = new Date();
            if (myDate > today) {
                alert("Entered date is greater than today's date ");
            }
            else {
                alert("Entered date is less than today's date ");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: thank you sir according to @Subodh Ghulaxe sir answer i have solved this..using setdate attribute in jquery ...now i am looking for end date validation it soulhd be 3 months futer date according to todays date

Answer (score 0):

include this script

```
// jQuery Date Picker
jQuery(".datepicker").datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: false,
    isRTL:false,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,

});
jQuery('.datepicker').css('cursor', 'pointer');
jQuery('.datepicker').attr("readonly", "readonly");
jQuery('.datepicker').addClass('tooltip-info');
jQuery('.datepicker').attr('data-rel', 'tooltip');
jQuery('.datepicker').attr('data-placement', 'right');
jQuery('.datepicker').attr('data-original-title', 'Select a Date');
jQuery(".datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd");
jQuery(".datepicker").datepicker("option", "showAnim", "slideDown");
jQuery(".datepicker").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).datepicker( "setDate", jQuery(this).attr('date-value'));
});
Use id="datepicker"
```

Comment: is there way to validate the date using jquery only..like after selecting date... it should check the date and validate it..using jquery only..and not datetimepicker